# Fix a CSS file: space after colon on rules but not selectors (Sublime Text 2)

Tags: css, sublimetext2

OK--I have a HUGE css file, inherited from another designer. I'm in the process of cleaning it. One thing I need to do is add a space after colon for rules but not selectors. i.e.:

```
.selector:after {
foo: bar;
}
```

Where I'm adding a space after foo: but NOT after .selector (between selector: and after).

I'm assuming there's an easier way to do this than find/replace and manually/visually skipping the selector colons, but any advice is appreciated.

Comment: [CSS prettifier](http://procssor.com/)

Comment: you would have to use a regular expression that looks for `}` then finds the `:'s` before the closing `}`.. i cant write a regExp's but that's what you need. or the prettifier should work from above since it was posted while i was typing.

Comment: OK, that worked! (ProCSSr). Awesome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why creating a regular expression would work very well. I think the easiest and quickest way would be to simple use your IDE's find and replace to add a space after each colon and then use find and replace again to remove the space from your pseudo classes. Since there are probably only around 8 different pseudo classes used it shouldn't take to long to prform a find a replace on each.

Comment: I'm very tempted to do that, actually. I'm having trouble with ProCSSor because my inherited file is 6000+ lines, and ProCSSor seems to stop after 1300 or so. I've contacted them about it (I purchased the app through the app store, $5 is too good a bargain, and I want to support great apps). So as of right now I still haven't solved the problem cleanly.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using [ProCssor](http://procssor.com/), this is so very cool, thanks SteveAx.

Comment: Ooh, not so fast. As mentioned above, my 6000 line css file isn't going through all the way, the processor stops at around 1300 or so. Sigh.

Answer (score 0):

This would take about 5 seconds in Sublime text, I would do this:

- Highlight `:` with the cursor
- alt+f3 to select all instances of the colon
- hit the right arrow key to jump to the right of the colon
- add a space

If you want to "normalize" and make sure there are no double spaces after the colon, just add two spaces after one of the colons, and do alt+f3 to select all instances of it and correct it.